# Creating a Qt fullscreen window which is transparent for input

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5, x11

I would like to create, with PyQt5, a fullscreen window which is always on top and transparent to input: that is, clicks pass through it as though it is not there and it cannot take focus.

Using a very basic program:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = QWidget()
    w.setWindowFlags(Qt.WindowTransparentForInput)
    w.showFullScreen()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

this fails. If I do not set `Qt.WindowTransparentForInput` then it works fine; the window is fullscreen as expected. Of course, though, it intercepts clicks. Adding `Qt.WindowTransparentForInput` means that the window will no longer become full screen; it appears at some sort of random size. Similarly, windows with `Qt.WindowTransparentForInput` set do not respond properly to the `resize()` method. How can I have a window which is transparent for input at a size and position I request?

Comment: Your code works for me with Qt / PyQt 5.15.1 and Python 3.8.7.